# Convert specific video and audio track only with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have an MKV file (`vidui.mkv`) with 6 tracks in it.

```
Track 1 - video - xvid - 1920x1080
Track 2 - video - xvid - 720x576
Track 3 - audio -  AAC - 1240kbps - English
Track 4 - audio -  AAC - 648kbps - Spanish
Track 5 - audio -  AAC - 648kbps - Commentary 1
Track 6 - audio -  AAC - 648kbps - Commentary 2
```

I want to convert the above file to a mp4 format with one h264 video and one AC3 audio. Also I want to convert track 1 (video) and track 5(audio).

If I use

```
ffmpeg.exe -i vidui.mkv -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -crf 20 -sn -n vidui.mp4
```

it converts the first video track and first audio track, but what I would like it to do is convert track 1 and track 5.

Comment: It would be nice to see the command used to generate this track listing.

Answer (score 91):

You can use the [`-map` option](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) ([full documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)) to select specific input streams and map them to your output.

The most simple `map` syntax you can use is `-map i:s`, where `i` is the input file ID and `s` is the stream ID, both starting with `0`. In your case, that means we select track `0` and `4`:

```
ffmpeg -i vidui.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -crf 20 -map 0:0 -map 0:4 vidui.mp4
```

If you want to choose video, audio or subtitle tracks specifically, you can also use [stream specifiers](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers):

```
ffmpeg -i vidui.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -crf 20 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 vidui.mp4
```

Here, `0:v:0` is the first video stream and `0:a:1` is the second audio stream.

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically? Say I want to do this only to audio tracks of language X, and have ffmpeg pick this up?

Comment: @Freedo Yes, please see the documentation. For example `-map 0:m:language:eng`

Comment: On a side note, by default [not all streams](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Defaultbehavior) are chosen.