# ffmpeg - replace audio in video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

How to replace the audio in a video file using an audio file using ffmpeg?

I imagine the command looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.wav -MAGIC video-new.mp4
```

This is very similar to [How to replace an audio stream in a video file with multiple audio streams?](https://superuser.com/questions/800234/how-to-replace-an-audio-stream-in-a-video-file-with-multiple-audio-streams) but that question handles multiple audio tracks, which complicates it very much, making it unclear which part of the solution is enough for a simple audio swap.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You will want to copy the video stream without re-encoding to save a lot of time but re-encoding the audio might help to prevent incompatibilities:

```
ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.wav -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 new.mp4
```

`-map 0:v:0` maps the first (index `0`) video stream from the input to the first (index `0`) video stream in the output.

`-map 1:a:0` maps the second (index `1`) audio stream from the input to the first (index `0`) audio stream in the output.

If the audio is longer than the video, you will want to add `-shortest` before the output file name.

Not specifying an audio codec, will automatically select a working one. You can specify one by for example adding `-c:a libvorbis` after `-c:v copy`. You can also use `-c copy` to avoid re-encoding the audio, but this has lead to compatibility and synchronization problems in my past.

Comment: or directly `-c copy` to just re-mux audio and video without re-encoding any of the streams ^^

Comment: Do you know how to convert the new audio on the same format (with the same parameters) as it is in original video?
I mean, I need the new audios to be encoded in the same way as it was the old audio.

Comment: Works like charm!!

Comment: @Kostanos not automatically but I would like to. Please ask another question. You can reference this one to clarify that yours is new.

Comment: Please, help: [segmentation fault when trying to replace audio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60779743/12141355)

Comment: @FrancescoYoshiGobbo - could you expand on that? How much of the rest of the command remains after `-c copy`? Obviously the new filename - what else? If you could provide a complete revised command, that would be helpful.

Comment: @almcnicoll - if the audio files we are going to substitute have the same or compatible codec, the re-encoding is not necessary and a `ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.m4a -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 new.mp4` would suffice. Or alternatively if the 2 streams are going to be muxed into an `.mkv` container, so on the code above we can substitute `.m4a` with the original `.wav` of the question and the `new.mp4` with `new.mkv`.

Comment: I agree with Francesco to use `-c copy` instead of `-c:v copy`. `-c:v copy` means to copy the video only, which means re-encoding the audio. `-c copy` will copy both the video and audio, no re-encoding.

Comment: worked on ffmpeg v4.3 win10. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly when trying to put wav into my h265 file I get: `Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters`

Comment: Needed to pull out the audio from a video, de-noise it, and re-insert it.  This was perfect.

Comment: I tried but the video is not visible. what is the reason?

Comment: `-shortest` didn't work for me. It still kept the video as long as the audio. `-fflags shortest` worked instead.

Comment: For some reason it have length from audio file. bur after video stream ends -- picture is on pause.

Answer (score 1):

If your video file contains subtitle tracks or multiple audio tracks, the above solution by @qubodup will discard the subtitle tracks but keep all the non-first audio tracks in the video. In that case, you should use the following command line as a more general solution:

```
ffmpeg -y -i v.mp4 -i a.m4a -c copy -map 0 -map -0:a -map 1:a video-new.mp4
```

This will replace all audio tracks in the video file `v.mp4` by all audio tracks in the audio file `a.m4a`, keeping all other tracks including video tracks and subtitle tracks intact.

For better understanding, `-map 0` selects all tracks (including all audio/video/subtitle tracks) from the first input file (index starts from `0`); `-map -0:a` discard all audio tracks from the first input file; `-map 1:a` select all audio tracks from the second input file. In particular, `1:a:0` means the first (the last '0') audio track (the middle 'a') of the second input file (the first '1'), discarding the 3rd number (i.e., becomes `1:a`) means all that type of tracks (audio tracks), discarding the 2nd number (i.e., becomes `1`) mean all types of tracks. The -ve sign means subtraction.

For detailed explanation on FFMPEG's `-map` option, you can refer to [FFMPEG Advanced Options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)