# Steps to troubleshoot lost audio and subtitles after using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have a video file in which the video and subtitles are about 27.3 seconds ahead of the audio. I'd like to sync them back up. I followed the instructions on this post: [In ffmpeg, how to delay only the audio of a .mp4 video without converting the audio?](https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au) but the result was that I lost both the subtitles and the audio entirely.

I ran this command:

`ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -itsoffset 27.3 -i "input.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy "movie-audio-delayed.mp4"`

And the result is that the video time stamps are still the same (at a glance at least -- watching in VLC, the scene at 11:42 is identical in both versions) but the output has no subtitles and no audio.

How do I figure out what I a doing wrong here?